# Remapping C-w in isearch

Tags: isearch

Currently when performing `evil-search-forward` , pressing `C-w` causes the cursor to yank and append the current word to the search (because that's what isearch does).

I'd like to change that to the usual delete-word, but remapping it in `isearch-mode-map` causes the under the cursor to get deleted.

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong about deleting the word under cursor if you've remapped `C-w` to delete the word under cursor. Please go into more detail.

Comment: Try typing `F1 k C-w` in appropriate context to see which keymap you should modify.

Comment: so what I really want is to delete a word in the minibuffer, since that's my search query, however, when I rebind `evil-search-forward`, in addition to messing up my minibuffer in a weird way, the buffer also has its word deleted

Also it appears that `isearch-yank-word-or-char` is originally bound to this function.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I want to delete a word from the search query, which resides in the minibuffer

Comment: BTW, this question is *not* about Evil, but isearch. I've changed title and tags accordingly.

Comment: The mention of `C-w` being "the usual `delete-word`" now makes no sense, as `C-w` would normally be `kill-region`. I presume this did make sense in the original evil context. In any case it's not clear to me *which* word of the search pattern is to be deleted here, so some clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remapping keys in isearch is nothing special, however isearch is not using the minibuffer, but the echo area for displaying its state.  This means that trying to use a conventional editing command like `delete-word` will not have the intended effect (deleting a word in the minibuffer), but rather edit text in the buffer you started the search from.

To solve this, you must write your own function in the style of what's been bound to `C-w` before, manipulating isearch state.  Judging by the sources of `isearch-delete-char`, you're working with a sequence of isearch commands (one for each char) and can pop these to undo what has been typed.  I'd consider reporting a bug to request this feature to be implemented as it's not obvious how you'd do it yourself.

Comment: I probably don't have the knowledge to write such a function yet. Cheers for the info